# Expectation value of potential operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, potential, notation

A book says $$\langle r|V|r\rangle$$=$$\sum_{a,a'}\int \psi^*_a(r)V_{aa'}\psi_{a'}(r) $$
define $$\langle r|\psi\rangle=\psi(r)$$

---

my derivation is $$\langle r|V|r\rangle=\langle r|\psi_a\rangle\langle \psi_a|V| \psi_{a'}\rangle\langle\psi_{a'}| r\rangle=\sum_{a,a'}\int \psi_a(r)V_{aa'}\psi^*_{a'}(r) $$
Am I wrong? It's different from the answer from book. I am not familiar with the bra-ket notation much.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you are right and the book wrong.

Comment: This is not so clear.  Which book?

Answer (score 1):

Your result and the book's result are equivalent assuming that $V_{aa'} = V_{a'a}$.  This is because
$$
\sum_{a,a'}\int \psi_a(r)V_{aa'}\psi^*_{a'}(r) = \sum_{a,a'}\int \psi^*_{a'}(r)V_{aa'}\psi_a(r)
$$
and if we then relabel the dummy indices $a$ and $a'$ to switch their role, this is equal to
$$ \sum_{a,a'}\int \psi^*_{a}(r)V_{a'a}\psi_{a'}(r) = \sum_{a,a'}\int \psi^*_{a}(r)V_{aa'}\psi_{a'}(r).
$$

So if the book was discussing an operator for which $V_{aa'} = V_{a'a}$, then there is no difference between your expression and theirs.  However, it is also worth noting that a general Hermitian operator $V$ satisfies $V_{aa'} = V^*_{a'a}$;  and in the more general case, your expression is the correct one.